# What is wrong with this basic computed data value using Vue2 JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have followed a tutorial online that uses computed data to output the first name and last name. My code is the same, but the rendered result is different. Presently, it is seeing what is after the $ as just a string and not the assigned data. https://screenshots.firefox.com/pDElTgV9EB58BjbS/127.0.0.1 What am I doing wrong?

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        bobby: {
            first: "Bobby",
            last: "Boone",
            age: 25
        },
        john: {
            first: "John",
            last: "Boone",
            age: 35,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        bobbyFullName() {
            return '${this.bobby.first} ${this.bobby.last}'
        },
        johnFullName() {
            return '${this.john.first} ${this.john.last}'
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>Name: {{bobbyFullName}}</h1>
        <p>Age {{bobby.age}}</p>

        <h1>Name: {{johnFullName}}</h1>
        <p>Age {{john.age}}</p>

    </div>
    `
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JS template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) uses backticks and not single quotes.

```
computed: {
    bobbyFullName() {
        return `${this.bobby.first} ${this.bobby.last}`;
    },
    johnFullName() {
        return `${this.john.first} ${this.john.last}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the return part needs to use ` and not '. You need eyes of a hawk to see that https://youtu.be/h6lhOYv-QM4?t=108

Comment: Exactly, otherwise it's gonna be treated as normal strings.